# fglut/libfglut.a(freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'

Tags: makefile, compilation

I am compiling a C++ program using make, this is the error i'm getting.

> /usr/bin/ld: fglut/libfglut.a(freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
>
> //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile:55: recipe for target 'morphlines' failed
>
> make: *** [morphlines] Error 1

I'm beginner

Answer (score 3):

> /usr/bin/ld: fglut/libfglut.a(freeglut_state.o):

This tells me you link `libfglut` *statically* (`*.a` is just an archive of object files). When you do this, you *must* link all dependencies as well, because with the object files from the static library actually compiled into your program, your program will depend on them.

Either link `libfglut` dynamically (this is the default with the GNU toolchain), so your program will depend on `libfglut.so` which will itself depend on `libX11.so` -- or add `-lX11` **after** `-lfglut` on the command line of your final linking step. You might need `-Wl,-Bdynamic` before `-lX11` to switch the linker back to dynamic linking.

If this doesn't directly solve your problem, I suggest you edit your question to include the relevant parts of the `Makefile` you're using.

Comment: @user2371524 : Can you explain in more detail how to do this for beginners!