# How to embed glut library into c++ project?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++, glut

I have a c++ project but when distribute this, need install libglut.so.3.:

```
./bin: error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I want the user not to have to install this dependency. How to embed the library into project?

I try compile as static library in c++ project using g++. My make file contains:

```
@g++ \
    -o bin \
    -std=c++11 \
    main.cpp \
    -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut \
    ;
```

I try define glut as static library:

```
-lm -lGL -lGLU -Wl,-Bstatic -lglut -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

But the compiler says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.a(libglut_la-freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I try download freeglut-3.0.0 and compile as static library:

Change `CMakeLists.txt` file for static compile:

```
OPTION(FREEGLUT_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build FreeGLUT shared library." OFF)
OPTION(FREEGLUT_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build FreeGLUT static library." ON)
```

And in the `CMakeCache.txt`:

```
//Build FreeGLUT shared library.
FREEGLUT_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF

//Build FreeGLUT static library.
FREEGLUT_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS:BOOL=ON
```

And compile it:

```
$ cmake .
$ make
[ 62%] Built target freeglut_static
...
[100%] Built target shapes_static
```

And verify:

```
$ ll lib/libglut.a 
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 690860 nov 17 19:11 lib/libglut.a
$ file lib/libglut.a
lib/libglut.a: current ar archive
```

Now, change the makefile:

```
-lm -lGL -lGLU freeglut-3.0.0/lib/libglut.a
```

And compile:

```
$ make
usr/bin/ld: freeglut-3.0.0/lib/libglut.a(fg_state_x11.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

But, same error message.

In similar problem: [fglut/libfglut.a(freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634459/fglut-libfglut-afreeglut-state-o-undefined-reference-to-symbol-xgetwindowatt) , i try add x11 libraries into project:

```
-lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11 freeglut-3.0.0/lib/libglut.a
```

Or:

```
-lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -Wl,-Bstatic -lglut -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

But have a same error message. What happened?

Comment: Try replacing `-lX11` in your compile command with `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs x11)`. The undefined reference you're getting comes from Xlib, make sure you have it installed on your system.

Comment: The last time I was using GLUT it could be used as both DLL and OBJ. If you use DLL you need to ship it along with your executable. If you use OBJ then it is directly linked into your executable file and need nothing else. But not sure if the case for nowadays GLUT and LINUX

Comment: @Strongwill same problem, `pkg-config --cflags --libs x11` return `-lX11` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully linked my a GLUT program using this command

`g++ -o ogl-test main.cpp freeglut-3.0.0/lib/libglut.a -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXext -lXrandr -lXt -lXi`

Hopefully this will also work for you. Make sure you change the path to glut library.

Comment: Thanks, my final link is: `includes/freeglut-3.0.0/lib/libglut.a -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXext -lXrandr -lXt -lXi`, it work fine.